# How could be an initializer expression is "assignment-expression" by the grammer?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, expression, initializer

I have this sample of code:

```
struct S {};

S s = S();
```

Per my understanding, I see that `s = S()` in the declaration `S s = S()` is an *[init-declarator](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.decl.general#nt:init-declarator)* where `s` is a *[declarator](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.decl.general#nt:declarator)* and `= S()` is an *[initializer](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init.general#nt:initializer)*.

Also, I see that the *initializer* (`= S()`) is a *[brace-or-equal-initializer](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init.general#nt:brace-or-equal-initializer)* which is *"= initializer-clause"*. This means finally that `S()` is an *[initializer-clause](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init#nt:initializer-clause)*.

By the grammar, an *initializer-clause* is either an *assignment-expression* or a *braced-init-list*. Indeed, `S()` might not be a *braced-init-list*, but it may be an *assignment-expression.*

If my analysis is correct so far, I have a question here:

How `S()` is an *assignment-expression*? Where is the *[assignment-operator](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.ass#nt:assignment-operator)* in expression `S()`?

In other words, the grammar of *assignment-expression* is:

```
assignment-expression:
      conditional-expression
      yield-expression
      throw-expression
      logical-or-expression assignment-operator initializer-clause
```

how `S()` could be one of the above?

Similarly, the grammar of a *throw-expression* is

```
throw-expression:
    throw assignment-expression
```

how `S()` in statement `throw S();` is an *assignment-expression*?

Comment: `S()` is a *conditional-expression*, hence doesn't need an *assignment-operator*. This is how the grammar handles operator precedence. You need walk along a dozen different kinds of *??-expression*s, until you eventually reach *postfix-expression*, which covers `S()`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - _You need walk along a dozen different kinds of ??-expressions, until you eventually reach postfix-expression,_ which is `simple-type-specifier ( expression-list )` ?

Comment: Yep, I think that's the one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How `S()` is an assignment-expression?

Because it matches the first option [conditional-expression](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.cond#nt:conditional-expression) as shown below. Note the emphasized part in each section/part and that at the end we reach to `simple-type-specifier ( expression-listopt )` which is `S()`.

> assignment-expression:
>
> - **conditional-expression**
> - yield-expression
> - throw-expression
> - logical-or-expression assignment-operator initializer-clause

Next, we go to [conditional expression](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.cond#nt:conditional-expression):

> conditional-expression:
>
> - **logical-or-expression**
> - logical-or-expression ? expression : assignment-expression

Next, to [logical-or-expression](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.log.or#nt:logical-or-expression):

> logical-or-expression:
>
> - **logical-and-expression**
> - logical-or-expression || logical-and-expression

Next, to [logical-and-expression](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.log.and#nt:logical-and-expression):

> logical-and-expression:
>
> - **inclusive-or-expression**
> - logical-and-expression && inclusive-or-expression

From [inclusive-or-expression](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.or#nt:inclusive-or-expression):

> inclusive-or-expression:
>
> - **exclusive-or-expression**
> - inclusive-or-expression | exclusive-or-expression

Next, [exclusive-or-expression](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.xor#nt:exclusive-or-expression)

> exclusive-or-expression:
>
> - **and-expression**
> - exclusive-or-expression ^ and-expression

Now to [and-expression](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.bit.and#nt:and-expression)

> and-expression:
>
> - **equality-expression**
> - and-expression & equality-expression

From [relational-operator](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.eq#nt:equality-expression)

> equality-expression:
>
> - **relational-expression**
> - equality-expression == relational-expression
> - equality-expression != relational-expression

Next from [relational-expression](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.rel#nt:relational-expression)

> relational-expression:
>
> - **compare-expression**
> - relational-expression < compare-expression
> - relational-expression > compare-expression
> - relational-expression <= compare-expression
> - relational-expression >= compare-expression

Next to [compare-expression](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.spaceship#nt:compare-expression)

> compare-expression:
>
> - **shift-expression**
> - compare-expression <=> shift-expression

Next to [shift-expression](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.shift#nt:shift-expression)

> shift-expression:
>
> - **additive-expression**
> - shift-expression << additive-expression
> - shift-expression >> additive-expression

Next [additive-expression](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.add#nt:additive-expression)

> additive-expression:
>
> - **multiplicative-expression**
> - additive-expression + multiplicative-expression
> - additive-expression - multiplicative-expression

Next to [multiplicative-expression](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.mul#nt:multiplicative-expression)

> multiplicative-expression:
>
> - **pm-expression**
> - multiplicative-expression * pm-expression
> - multiplicative-expression / pm-expression
> - multiplicative-expression % pm-expression

Next to [pm-expression](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.mptr.oper#nt:pm-expression)

> pm-expression:
>
> - **cast-expression**
> - pm-expression .* cast-expression
> - pm-expression ->* cast-expression

Next to [cast-expression](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.cast#nt:cast-expression)

> cast-expression:
>
> - **unary-expression**
> - ( type-id ) cast-expression

Next to [unary-expression](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.unary.general#nt:unary-expression)

> unary-expression:
>
> - **postfix-expression**
> - unary-operator cast-expression
> - ++ cast-expression
> - -- cast-expression
> - await-expression
> - sizeof unary-expression
> - sizeof ( type-id )
> - sizeof ... ( identifier )
> - alignof ( type-id )
> - noexcept-expression
> - new-expression
> - delete-expression

Finally we reach [postfix-expression](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.post.general#nt:postfix-expression)

> postfix-expression:
>
> - primary-expression
> - postfix-expression [ expression-listopt ]
> - postfix-expression ( expression-listopt )
> - **simple-type-specifier ( expression-listopt )**
> - typename-specifier ( expression-listopt )
> - simple-type-specifier braced-init-list
> - typename-specifier braced-init-list
> - postfix-expression . templateopt id-expression
> - postfix-expression -> templateopt id-expression
> - postfix-expression ++
> - postfix-expression --
> - dynamic_cast < type-id > ( expression )
> - static_cast < type-id > ( expression )
> - reinterpret_cast < type-id > ( expression )
> - const_cast < type-id > ( expression )
> - typeid ( expression )
> - typeid ( type-id )